# Lyapunov Exponent

Tags: dynamical-systems, ergodic-theory

Suppose $(X,A,\mu)$ a probability space, where $X$ is a compact Riemann manifold, $T:X\to X$ a diffeomorphism and $T$ is a measure-preserving transformation( over the borel $\sigma$ algebra).
Prove that $\mu$- a.e   $x\in X$ there is the Lyapunov exponent,

$$\lambda(x):=\lim_{n\to \infty} \frac{1}{n}\log\|DT^n(x)\|$$

where the operator norm is defined as $\displaystyle\|L\|=\sup_{\|x\|=1}\|L(x)\|$

Comment: Hey you're doing dynamical systems as well! Where is this problem taken from?

Comment: @anegligibleperson Take from of my teacher. I don't know the book.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You can use the Subadditive Ergodic Theorem. Note that the sequence $\log{\|DT^n(x)\|}$ is subadditive.
To see this apply the chain rule to $\|DT^{n+m}(x)\|$.

Answer (score 3):

Let $(X, \mathcal{A}, \mu)$ be a probability space, where $X$ is a compact Riemann manifold, $T : X \rightarrow X$ is a diffeomorphism, and $T$ is a measure-preserving transformation over the Borel $\sigma$-algebra.

We want to prove that for almost every $x \in X$, there exists a Lyapunov exponent $\lambda(x)$ defined as follows:

$$
\lambda(x) := \lim_{{n \to \infty}} \frac{1}{n} \log \|D T^n(x)\|,
$$

where $\|D T^n(x)\|$ represents the operator norm of the derivative of $T^n$ at point $x$.

One can use Birkhoff's Ergodic Theorem

Birkhoff's ergodic theorem states that for any $L^1$ function $f : X \rightarrow \mathbb{R}$, the time average converges almost everywhere to the space average:

$$
\lim_{{n \to \infty}} \frac{1}{n} \sum_{{k=0}}^{n-1} f(T^k(x)) = \int_X f \, d\mu,
$$

for $\mu$-almost every $x \in X$. In our case, we apply this theorem to the function $f(x) = \log \|DT(x)\|$, yielding:

$$
\lim_{{n \to \infty}} \frac{1}{n} \sum_{{k=0}}^{n-1} \log \|D T^k(x)\| = \int_X \log \|D T(x)\| \, d\mu,
$$

for $\mu$-almost every $x \in X$.

Then we can analysis the Exponentiate and Rearrange

Using properties of logarithms, we rewrite the equation as:

$$
\lim_{{n \to \infty}} \log \left(\prod_{{k=0}}^{n-1} \|D T^k(x)\|\right)^{\frac{1}{n}} = \int_X \log \|D T(x)\| \, d\mu,
$$

and take the exponential on both sides:

$$
\lim_{{n \to \infty}} \left(\prod_{{k=0}}^{n-1} \|D T^k(x)\|\right)^{\frac{1}{n}} = e^{\int_X \log \|D T(x)\| \, d\mu},
$$

for $\mu$-almost every $x \in X$.

Limit Definition

We recognize that the left-hand side is the geometric mean of $\|DT^k(x)\|$ over $k = 0, 1, \ldots, n-1$, which is equivalent to the $n$-th root of their product. Thus, we can rewrite it as:

$$
\lim_{{n \to \infty}} \left(\|D T^n(x)\|\right)^{\frac{1}{n}} = e^{\int_X \log \|D T(x)\| \, d\mu},
$$

and finally, define $\lambda(x)$ as:

$$
\lambda(x) := \lim_{{n \to \infty}} \frac{1}{n} \log \|D T^n(x)\|,
$$

for $\mu$-almost every $x \in X$.